# MySQL query returns results without order

Tags: php, mysql, select, union

I am trying to organize a queries output in 'orderindex' order to display the list correctly in my php functions loop with mysql.

Currently my SQL query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NewCustInfo.Driver, SUBSTRING_INDEX(NewCustInfo.Driver, '/', -1) AS orderindex, SUBSTRING_INDEX(NewCustInfo.Driver, '/', 1) AS thedriver, NewCustInfo.id,NewCustInfo.Accomplished
 FROM NewCustInfo WHERE NewCustInfo.Driver REGEXP 'Test123/' AND NewCustInfo.Accomplished='0' ORDER BY orderindex DESC) DUMMY_ALIAS1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT PickupSlip.Driver, SUBSTRING_INDEX(PickupSlip.Driver, '/', -1) AS orderindex, SUBSTRING_INDEX(PickupSlip.Driver, '/', 1) AS thedriver, PickupSlip.id,PickupSlip.Accomplished
 FROM PickupSlip WHERE PickupSlip.Driver REGEXP 'Test123/' AND PickupSlip.Accomplished='0' ORDER BY orderindex DESC) DUMMY_ALIAS2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DeliverySlip.Driver, SUBSTRING_INDEX(DeliverySlip.Driver, '/', -1) AS orderindex, SUBSTRING_INDEX(DeliverySlip.Driver, '/', 1) AS thedriver, DeliverySlip.id,DeliverySlip.Accomplished
 FROM DeliverySlip WHERE DeliverySlip.Driver REGEXP 'Test123/' AND DeliverySlip.Accomplished='0' ORDER BY orderindex DESC) DUMMY_ALIAS3
```

I realize this is ordering by SELECT, rather than the entire query as a whole. Is there a way to order the full results of all 3 SELECTS?

e.g. turn the 3 selects into a variable, then somehow concatenate them into a single list, and then display with ORDER BY?

Comment: You could put them in array and then use some array sorting http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per mysql's syntax on [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html), place an order by clause after the last select:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a
```

Comment: I didn't even knew about that. Great solution

Comment: This is it, thank you! I should have read the documentation first... lol